# Xamarin IOs app not launching in device even project builds successfully after changing Git branch

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.IOs project along with a NetStandard project in my solution. I use Git for version controlling.

After switching Git branches, even though the solution builds successfully, I can't launch the application to an actual device.

Answer (score 0):

So far what have helped me is, closing and re-opening Visual Studio when this happens